# GYP/V8 - how to generate VS2008 project by default?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, v8, gyp

I try to build V8 with GYP (Windows 7 x64, VS2008 x32). The problem is that GYP generates VS2010 solution by default. How to change this GYP behavior to get my VS2008 solution? (What file to edit?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the *MSVSVersion.py* file

```py
def _CreateVersion(name, path, sdk_based=False):
  """Sets up MSVS project generation.
```

Setup is based off the GYP_MSVS_VERSION environment variable or whatever is
autodetected if GYP_MSVS_VERSION is not explicitly specified.

So in a command window type:

```
SET GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2008
```

Then build it:

```
python build\gyp_v8
```

And that did generate a VS2008 sln file.

Answer (score 1):

GYP will detect VS version using environment variables (maybe I had VS2010 previously?). Can manually edit python file in /pylib/gyp/MSVSVersion.py:

```
def _CreateVersion(name, path, sdk_based=False):
  """Sets up MSVS project generation.
  ...
  return versions[str(name)] //replace with your version
```

P.S. I tried to specify VS version on command line when generated projects but that didn't work.

Comment: apparently the env variable setting was broken for while (but now works): http://code.google.com/p/gyp/issues/detail?id=404